# Name for a function which splits a list every time the result of a predicate changes

Tags: list, split, functional-programming, naming

The function takes a list and a function which returns a Boolean and splits the list every time the result of function changes. As a diagram:

```
 +------+        +-+      +----+  +---+     
 |      |        | |      |    |  |   |     
-+      +--------+ +------+    +--+   +---- 
 ^      ^        ^ ^      ^    ^  ^   ^
```

The x axis being the list index and the y axis the result of the predicate function, the `^` indicating a split.

So my question is how a function like that (or a more general version of it) would be called.

(For my own implementation I'd been calling it `edgesplit`, since it splits on the [rising/falling] edges.)

EDIT:
To clarify: I'd like to know a common name for a function which does this, not it's name in a specific language or how I should call it. In effect: "What should I google for?".

Comment: what language ? java ? html ? c ?

Comment: `SplitListEveryTimeResultOfFunctionChanges`?

Comment: I'd go for `groupConsecutiveBy`. Don't name it after what it does, name it after what the result looks like: groups of successive list elements.

Comment: I don't think there's a common name for this kind of function. In Haskell, you'd write ``groupOn p = map snd . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . map (f >>= (,))`` (using a Schwartzian transform with [`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy))

Comment: That does sound a lot like *edge detection*.

Comment: @Bergi `groupBy` does 90% of what I'm implementing here, thanks! Was only looking at Prelude while searching for fitting functions. Using `groupOn p = groupBy ((==) \`on\` p)` I managed to be marginally faster than what I implemented. Your code snippet beat both (again by a margin), after modifying it a bit to get it to work: ``groupOn p = map (map snd) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . map (p >>= (,))``.